# Should we think about elections?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

We are down to [three rpg.se specific moderators](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Is this a non-issue since V2Blast is still around as an [Associate Community Manager for the Curator Support Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369260/please-welcome-valued-associates-958-v2blast-959-spencerg) and available for moderation, or should we think about holding elections due to the gap?

Comment: The moderators themselves have almost certainly already considered or been considering elections. It will ultimately be their call on whether to request them or not.

Comment: @doppelgreener their decision may end up being informed (either way) by the community however

Comment: I know the moderators page says we have three, but it should probably at least be acknowledged that one of them hasn’t been visibly active in a year.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov that is one thing that moved me to ask the question, I thought that framing the question like this was the best way to open up the discussion-

Comment: A note to potential answerers form an ex-mod: I'd urge that answers (either way) focus on impact to the site: flag-handling, unchecked trolling, responsiveness to pings, &c.

Comment: @Akixkisu I know, and I think your framing is appropriate; it's just one of those "someone had to say it" things.

Comment: We have a competent moderator team that, like any other team, sometimes makes mistakes. I believe that our moderators generally do a good job. But I also think that most of the points mentioned in [Do we want three moderators, or four?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6963/do-we-want-three-moderators-or-four) are still valid.

Comment: We ran with three mods for a good while, with mxy/was eagle/sevensided, and then went to two when waxy left. Four is a new model, which came with the elections that put doppel and nitsua on the panel.  Three might be a good enough number if our dear moose can still fulfill their role.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## An election is coming

The moderation team had already (prior to this Meta at least) discussed this with the CM team and determined that the team would like an election.

I believe an official announcement to that effect should be coming soon, with additional details.

Comment: We won't really make an announcement before the question collection starts but you can see the election info here - https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/6

Answer (score 4):

#### Whoops, my answer is OBE

It looks like the diamond mod team has already engaged with the CM before this meta was posed, so this answer has been **O**vercome **B**y **E**vents [now that @Rubiksmoose has responded](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11721/22566), which means that my trust in their good sense and judgment was warranted. I love it when I'm right.  But I'll leave my answer up because the system is working as it's been designed to work.

---

### Who's this "we," Kimo Sabe?

If the diamond mod team tells the CM that they need another diamond mod to take care of the work load, they'll ask the CM to call an election.

If there are particular mod issues that concern you, or any of us for that matter, or if you feel that our diamond mods, or a diamond mod, are not performing up to standards then you can contact the CM, or, you can contact the mod team directly and address it with them to see if your perceptions are shared by the whole diamond mod team and / or the CM.

Sometimes, where we sit determines (and informs what we see) - we may only have a part of the story.  In the case of how much work the diamond mods do in their roles on this SE, we (non diamond mods) for sure do **not** have the whole story.

I offer a reprise of [SevenSidedDie's nice meta post here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9621/22566) as regards what happens when the need arises as seen by the diamond mods.

> Stack Exchange generally consults with and defers to the moderator
> team about how many moderators there should be. It’s more about what
> the team feels the need for than anything else. The process is pretty
> much that a CM drops by the mod chat and asks how many election spots
> it should have and then sets it up. It’s pragmatic and not really much
> of a discussion. Mods poke a CM about an election, a CM shows up and
> asks how many and sets expectations about SE’s ability to schedule it
> in, then goes off and does it. Resignation timing—for actual removal
> of the diamond and any announcement—is discussed if necessary.

#### Bottom Line: No

No, "we" don't need to think about a mod election until the diamond mods decide that their ability to handle the work load, as unpaid volunteers, could use another hand and they contact the CM to set one up.

And I'll make one further observation: I find the quality of moderation in the past two years (since the last election) to have been good.  The diamond mods do a fine job as exception handlers and being all around good stack members.  Beyond that, each of them has shown me that I can trust their judgment and good sense.

Comment: Got quite confused at first when I thought you were suggesting your answer was a member of the Order of the British Empire...

Comment: "Who's this "we," Kimo Sabe?" The community. "No, "we" don't need to think about a mod election until the diamond mods decide that their ability to handle the work load, as unpaid volunteers, could use another hand" There's also other factors to consider, like bus factor and/or the possibility of another Monica situation decimating the moderators.

Comment: @nick012000 This bit is a non issue, in the context of this answer  and the facts of how the Stack is run / organized.     *or the possibility of another Monica situation decimating the moderators*  If mods leave it still requires the CMs to set up elections and replacements if the mods who do remain don't think they can handle the load.  The 'community' has no means to do anything about that. (What's a bus factor? Not familiar with that term)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor