# Informal 7th Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

**The purpose of this thread is to collect election questions before the election occurs when our questions happen.**

This Q&A is an opportunity for community members to pose questions to the yet unknown candidates on the topic of moderation whenever these questions are relevant to a specific moderation encounter. Often these encounters don't happen during the formal Q&A, and as things will, once they are out of sight, they are out of mind.

We may gather these questions here voluntarily, and then when the formal question gathering starts, we may or may not port them over as we see suitable and applicable to that 7th election.

This informal Q&A is a place to voice questions and issues that you are running into currently that you want to preserve for the next formal elections Q&A, not a place of discussion and resolution - please take those elsewhere where they may apply or develop into resolution processes.

Comment: I feel this will be buried way before the next election happens or get too long

Comment: @Trish It is here, so we can dig it out whenever it fits - as to the latter - that is fine.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this will be achieving that the existing question collections won't. I'd be totally happy for us to have a repository, but that might be well served by less focus on the 7th election (which is probably a long time in the future) and for good questions from previous elections (presumably the generally applicable ones) to be ported to a CW here.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Focusing on the 7th election follows the general format and keeps the focus on current issues between elections - the 6th and 7th, and so on (which would require a new question for the 7th to 8th election-span). Currently, we have different places that look at issues from particular elections, which already function as repositories for those elections.

Comment: Most moderator questionnaire questions wind up being about present issues the site is facing at the time of the election, or faced quite recently, and ask the moderator pointed questions a new moderator would have to face in order to assess their suitability for the issues the site currently faces. Even some of our current staples originated that way. Preparing questions for the theoretical future seems to lack the _grit_ that forms these questions. The issues we face today might be long resolved and learned from by the time the next election rolls around and call for different questions then.

Comment: @doppelgreener correct "we may or may not port them over as we see suitable and applicable to that 7th election." So we decide at that time what has the grit.

Comment: @doppelgreener All that this Q&A does is extend the period of formulating those questions when one perceives them.  It is a tangible option to address the issue of not having enough time to do so - voiced with emphasis during the last election. I see the backlash from moderators and former moderators here, and frankly, I ask myself - what have you done to address this issue, and why do you feel the need to throw the weight of your reputation behind preventing this?

Comment: I'm not trying to give backlash. I am sharing my concerns about the effectiveness of this particular Q&A as feedback. To the extent my words have weight, that's why I took time considering then before posting them.

Comment: @doppelgreener To what purpose?

Comment: @Akixkisu For the purpose of providing feedback on a Q&A that's not being well received, as to why it might be struggling?

Comment: @doppelgreener My bad, I formulated that poorly: What is the goal of your feedback -what do you intend to achieve by sharing it - who do you address, etc.?

Comment: No, you formed it fine and I answered it. Do you have questions about my feedback beyond "why does it exist"? I feel like I'm having to justify its existence to some arbitrary measure I don't see, and I don't think I should be required to do that.

Comment: @doppelgreener Here is my conundrum: I don't see anything about your feedback as actionable or not already addressed. So either I'm missing your point by a mile, or you are suggesting that I should delete this meta altogether as inherently flawed, or you aren't addressing me, but instead address people who are reading this, and you are conveying information to them.

Comment: See extended discussion https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/informal-7th-moderator-election-qa--question-collection-extended

Comment: I upvoted, I don't see the issue with asking this. Most sites are dying for more Meta participation, and here you are with a well-written question that gets well-downvoted.

Answer (score -6):

Someone posted a partial answer to a question that asks to clarify a specific misconception within the question. You receive a flag - how do you act in this situation?

Comment: I don't feel this is a good question to be directed toward potential moderators. Instead it is an issue that should be decided on meta. Mods are not politicians running on a platform of "I will handle flags X way...", they are just trying to show they are capable of moderating fairly and showing good judgement.

Comment: @linksassin This is a question about showing judgement, so ecactly in line with what I want to know from potential moderators.

Comment: I disagree, you are asking them to judge a hypothetical situation where the best answer is; "it depends on the details". Moderator questions should allow candidates to demonstrate they can be trusted to make good judgements, not ask them to judge theoretical specifics without enough detail to make an informed judgement.

Comment: "I have not enough detail - this is how I go about collecting the detail" - any insight like that - I'd welcome. Hypotheticals show exactly how someone approaches a problem that lacks a clear solution. During the last election on arcade, this type of question helped me arrive at a ranking conclusion - it served me excellently. I regret not asking similar questions to other candidates during the last election on rpg.se.

Comment: @linksassin I also disagree with your statement. I'm trying to find the best possible option, mostly from a group of qualified people, who, I already know, are well capable of making good judgements.

Comment: Is this based on some current or recent event?  Or is it whole-cloth hypothetical?

Comment: @Novak [Recent event.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/conversation-about-a-partial-answer-in-comments)

Comment: @Novak This stems from a chain of four separate incidents during the last two months, the last two were the one that OS linked, and another declined flag that resulted in me asking this https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193244/44723 and flagging as NLN instead.

Comment: It sounds like you might be better served with a new meta question about what criteria should be used when judging answers in comments, rather than a question-as-answer in this meta question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the events (or traces thereof) in question.  And I also think that if this is an actual issue that needs solving it should be its own meta, and if it isn't then it probably shouldn't be a driver in whatever election may happen further down the line.

Comment: Coming at this issue (if it even *is* an issue) obliquely, without giving direct references to it until asked, and not even in a question dedicated to it, just looks *weird.*  I'll be honest-- it's probably not your intent, but it looks like a public grievance list.  I was on the fence before, but I'll be downvoting the question itself, now.

Comment: @Novak I don't think anyone involved thinks that we need to have a meta about the topic (except maybe OS?). If you are curious, I added a link to the extended discussion as a comment under the main post.

Comment: @Novak I was just wondering why something that was obvious to me was not obvious to the mod that reviewed my flag, and they were very helpful in clearing things up. Definitely don't need a meta about it.

Comment: If it doesn't need a meta, why would it possibly be a driver in a moderator election which probably won't happen for years?

Comment: @Novak https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11848/informal-7th-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/11849?noredirect=1#comment40784_11849

Comment: I upvoted, but doesn't the moderator candidate need more details in order to answer this question?

Comment: @user1271772 Hm, I will think on it - but if you have a good idea how to rephrase it, then I'm all ears :)